# Toast message shows time in EST

Tags: java, android

Why below code in Android activity shows a toast message with timestamp in EST instead of local timezone? I'm in PST & my PC clock is also in PST but toast message shows up in EST

```
    long time = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis() + 10000l;
    Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
    Toast.makeText(context, "Next Weekly Check Scheduled at " + new Timestamp(time), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Note: It shows EST in emulator. If I uncheck the auto select timezone & set it manually to PST in emulator, then it works but I don't want to set it manually every time since I wipe emulator data. Any solution to this? Not sure if this is a bug in emulator.

Comment: can you change the emulator to your time?

Comment: It works but why by default emulator shows time in EST???

Comment: the emulator is probably just set up that way, when you put it on an actual device you won't have any problems with it so it shouldn't be a very big deal right?

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to test it on emulator rather than actual device & wanted to know if anyone experience the same issue?